# Delphi, ListView, how to remove the margin between items in vsIcon

Tags: delphi, listview

Using Delphi XE3, Listview in vsIcon mode with an imagelist assigned.

I add a few items and assign them an ImageIndex, and there is a very large spacing/margin between each image/item, how can I change that? Is it possible at all without custom drawing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`ListView_SetIconSpacing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro

```
uses commctrl;
..
ListView_SetIconSpacing(ListView1.Handle, 36, 36);
ListView1.Arrange(arAlignTop);  // refresh view
```

Refer to the documentation, the values must include icon sizes, otherwise the icons overlap each other.

You can reset the view by sending '-1' for cx and cy and the return value is the current spacing, so for instance, to decrease spacing with a certain amount, you can do:

```
var
  Spacing: DWORD;
begin
  Spacing := ListView_SetIconSpacing(ListView1.Handle, WORD(-1), WORD(-1));
  ListView_SetIconSpacing(ListView1.Handle,
                          LoWord(Spacing) - 10, HiWord(Spacing) - 6);
  ListView1.Arrange(arAlignTop);
```

Comment: @Marjan, Well it's a one liner in commctrl.pas. :) AFAIK we have one liners for many/most macros, like RGB() for instance. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Only issue with this, is the selection boundaries overlap the next icons, I guess the only workaround for it is gonna be custom drawing? http://i.imgur.com/2nZvk.png

Comment: @hikari - Looks like the control is reserving space for text labels. I don't know if there's any way to get rid of it.

Comment: For a probably better view try set the font size of the list view to something small, like 1, and leave room at least for 4 pixels plus icon size. That 4 pixels is probably important as it is also mentioned in the documentation. You're not using text labels anyway..

Comment: Thanks! that was it, setting the font to 1 solved the overlapping :)